# How to prevent SelectedIndexChanged event from firing in ListBox after removing an item from it

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

I am working on selecting an item which will cause deletion of selected item. The problem is that when I delete an item I am selecting additional item which cause another deletion...

How do I unselest/deselect after deleting selected item?

This causes my problem:

```
    void lbMessage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = new DialogResult();

        result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove this item?", "Removal Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            lbMessage.Items.Remove(lbMessage.SelectedItem); 
            lbMessage.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }

    private void btnAddMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbMessage.Items.Add(txtMessage.Text);
        txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: The reason that it doesn't seem straightforward is that this is a poor UI design. In general, you don't delete items by selecting them in a Listbox. There is **almost** always a delete button that you click after making your selection.

Comment: @Chris Shain, I do think it's worthy to implement in any program. Having additional button kind of make me feel like it rises complexity of small app. I do like my solution.

Comment: @ChrisShain I agree, the delete button is pretty standard, one alternative would be a second listbox with include and exclude buttons.

Comment: Simplicity is not always an option. I do like my solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try removing the `SelectedIndexChanged` event before removing the item, then add it back in:

```
private void lbMessage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove this item?", 
                      "Remove Confirmation", 
                      MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                      MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes) {
    lbMessage.SelectedIndexChanged -= lbMessage_SelectedIndexChanged;
    lbMessage.Items.Remove(lbMessage.SelectedItem);
    lbMessage.SelectedIndexChanged += lbMessage_SelectedIndexChanged;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting `SelectedIndex = -1` is raising the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.  Check if there is nothing selected at the start of the event.

```
void lbMessage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (lbMessage.SelectedIndex == -1) return;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the events list for `lbMessage` and make sure the correct method is listed next to `SelectedIndexChanged`.

Answer (score 1):

If you like it that way without a delete button then just do this:

```
bool isAfterDelete = false;
void lbMessage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isAfterDelete)
    {
        isAfterDelete = false;
        return;
    }
    DialogResult result = new DialogResult();

    result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove this item?", 
                             "Removal Confirmation", 
                             MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                             MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        lbMessage.Items.Remove(lbMessage.SelectedItem); 
        isAfterDelete = true;
        lbMessage.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to place the "isAfterDelete = true;" before the Remove call because this function will change the indexing of the list box which results in another call into "SelectedIndexChanged" before the bool is set.

Answer (score 0):

What if you just either wrap your code an in if() that checks for lbMessage.SelectedIndex == -1, or write a check for it at the beginning and return if it's true:

```
void lbMessage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(lbMessage.SelectedIndex == -1)
    return;

    DialogResult result = new DialogResult();

    result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove this item?", "Removal Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        lbMessage.Items.Remove(lbMessage.SelectedItem); 
        lbMessage.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see the comment "// Your code here"? You need to put the code in your current method there. The if()/return is meant to just be an addition.

Comment: You unlinked the event or something then. When you click on an item in the ListBox, this event should be called and SelectedIndex will be the index of the item you clicked. The code for the method is correct.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the whole method. Hopefully that fixes it for you.

Comment: This will not work because the 'SelectedIndexChanged' event will be called immediately after the Remove function before the "SelectedIndex" is set to -1.

Comment: @Wizetux, `ListBox.Items.Remove(ListBox.SelectedItem)` intrinsically sets `ListBox.SelectedIndex = -1` because the selected item is no longer in the list, so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The shear act of removing the item from the Items collection causes the items to change their index. This thus calls the "SelectedIndexChanged" event again on the list box. To prevent this, you would need to set a flag before the remove function to indicate that the SelectedIndexChange is being called after the 
remove and prevent the event from occuring.  You can do that by the following.

```
    private bool afterRemove = false;
    void lbMessage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (afterRemove)
        {
            afterRemove = false;
            return;
        }

        DialogResult result = new DialogResult();

        result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove this item?", "Removal Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            afterRemove = true;
            lbMessage.Items.Remove(lbMessage.SelectedItem); 
            // Another call to "lbMessage_SelectedIndexChanged" is made right here.
       }
    }

    private void btnAddMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbMessage.Items.Add(txtMessage.Text);
        txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

An alternative that might be easier to understand could be the following.

```
    private bool afterRemove = false;
    void lbMessage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (afterRemove)
            return;

        DialogResult result = new DialogResult();

        result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove this item?", "Removal Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            afterRemove = true;
            lbMessage.Items.Remove(lbMessage.SelectedItem); 
            // Another call to "lbMessage_SelectedIndexChanged" is made right here.
            afterRemove = false;
       }
    }
```